# Django Models,There's a column in the table, but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query,

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I've defined some models in django and I can successfully add data to them using objects in django but the problem is that when I try to do this directly from the database it gives me this "HINT" `There's a column named origin_id in the table flight, but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query`, I'm using postgresql for the database, So can anyone please help me with this? I know there are similar questions like this but I couldn't find the solution.

```
class AirportManager(models.Manager):
    @classmethod
    def ret(cls):
         return 'This is a custom "Manager"'
    @classmethod
    def code(cls):
        obj = Airport.objects.all()
        return obj

class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    objects = AirportManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'airport'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} ({self.code})"

class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Airport,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Airport,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = "arrivals")
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    flights = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'flight'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'from "{self.origin}" to "{self.destination}" in "{self.duration}" hrs'
```

Comment: what did you try to do directly?

Comment: @bb4L I just wanted to better understand what's happening behind the scenes, Even if I might nor need to do it directly but still I just wanted to know the reason behind that situation.